# Is it possible to put a bunch of -Wno_... gcc flags into a file and reference that on the command line?

Tags: gcc, warnings

gcc has so many warning options, and I want to turn a bunch of them off (I'm compiling a ton of old code that's known to work, but generates lots of warnings).  I suppose I could turn off all warnings, but surely that's not advisable, but I also don't want to set my CFLAGS to contain 10's of -Wno_... flags that will appear on the screen as each module compiles.

What would be ideal would be to be able to put a bunch of these flags into a text file and reference *that* on the command line.  Maybe that's possible, but I can't find an option for that in the manual pages.  Anybody know if such an option exists?

Answer (score 1):

Files containing commandline options to be used in the way you envisage
are often called *response files*.

GCC compilers support response files, which may contain any or
all of the commandline arguments (not just `-opt` options). The usage is:

```
gcc [args...] @file [more args...]
```

where `file` is a file of space-separated commandline arguments.
`@file` is documented in the GCC manual in [3.2 Options Controlling the Kind of Output](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html)

If you like response files for your personal builds, feel free.
But in professional build practice they are not popular. Consider that Exhibit A for
the the diagnosis of a build break or problematic build is the complete build
log, in which we hope to find the complete sequence of commands with
all of their arguments. `@file` frustrates that hope, and holds us up while we look for
`file` or ask somebody remote to send it to us, or post its contents (perhaps on Stackoverflow!)
When we see it, it can be difficult or impossible to eliminate the eventuality that what we are seeing is
not actually what was in `file` when the build was run. Build logs filled with
multi-kilobyte command lines are normal and are everyday reading for build engineers.